# evento onchange solo funciona una vez

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, select, eventos

hola tengo un formulario con varios campos y un select deseo que apartir de un select que se llena con un array que contiene procedimientos;que si selecciono x procedimiento se llame a la funcion habilitar() que es la que me habilita o deshabilita mas campos del formulario intente con la funcion onchange y funciona pero solo la primer vez si vuelvo a seleccionar otra opcion esta ya no hace nada **quisiera que constantemente este leyendo la opcion que selecciona el usuario y siempre llame la funcion habilitar agradezco pudieran ayudarme aca el codigo:**
cabe resaltar que para deshabilitar los campos hago una validacion con la constante procedures de la que obtengo el valor desde el elemento select

///////////elemento select///////////////7

```
<label><?php echo trans('medical-histories.procedure_code'); ?></label>
            <select data-name="procedure_code_autocompletation" id="inputprocedures" class="js-example-basic-single" name="state" onchange="habilitar()">
             <option value=""></option>
             <option selected>Selecciona un procedimiento medico</option>
             <?php foreach ($proceduresList as $item){ ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $item->name; ?>"><?php echo $item->name; ?></option>
            <?php
            } ?>
            </select>
```

javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            const procedures = document.getElementsByName("state");
            const attention = document.getElementById('personal_attention');
            const mainDiagnosis = document.getElementById('main_diagnosis');
            const fDiagnosisRel = document.getElementById('f_related_code');
            const sDiagnosisRel = document.getElementById('s_related_code');
            const relWay = document.getElementById('realization_way_surgical_act');
            const complications = document.getElementById('complications');

        function habilitar() {
            const case1 = '735301 - ASISTENCIA DEL PARTO CON O SIN EPISIORRAFIA O PERINEORRAFIA';
            const case2 = '735930 - ASISTENCIA DEL PARTO ESPONTÁNEO GEMELAR O MÚLTIPLE';
            const case3 = '735931 - ASISTENCIA DEL PARTO INTERVENIDO GEMELAR O MÚLTIPLE';
            const case4 = '735980 - OTRA ASISTENCIA MANUAL DEL PARTO ESPONTÁNEO';
            
            if (procedures == case1) {
                attention.disabled = false;
            } else if (procedures == case2  ) {
                attention.disabled = false;
            } else if (procedures == case3  ) {
                attention.disabled = false;
            } else if (procedures == case4 ) {
                attention.disabled = false;
            } else {
                attention.disabled = true;
            }
            const quirurjico = JSON.parse('<?php echo Json_encode($Quirurjicos); ?>');
            if (quirurjico.find((quirurji) => quirurji.name === procedures.value)) {
                mainDiagnosis.disabled = false;
                fDiagnosisRel.disabled = false;
                sDiagnosisRel.disabled = false;
                relWay.disabled = false;
                complications.disabled = false;
                console.log('El procedimiento se ha encontrado')
            } else {
                mainDiagnosis.disabled = true;
                fDiagnosisRel.disabled = true;
                sDiagnosisRel.disabled = true;
                relWay.disabled = true;
                complications.disabled = true;
                console.log('El procedimiento NO se ha encontrado')

            }
        }
        $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.js-example-basic-single').select2();
});
console.log(procedures)
    </script>
```

Comment: Y en donde escuchas el onchange en ese script?..

Comment: que pena no se soy nuevo en esto y aun no comprendo bien hay solo llamo la funcion habilitar apenas ocurre el primer cambio peroya no se que hacer para que vuelva y lo escuche y vuelva y ejecute la funcion

Comment: te deje un script revisalo y checa si te es útil. Quizas con solo cambiar un par de lineas te es funcional, analizalo y revisa si te puede aplicar a tu estructura del case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mira por no dejar te pongo la forma en que lo utilizo yo, a lo mejor te sirve:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
            $("#Motivo_Baja<?=$a+1?>").on('change',function()  {
                $("#Motivo_Baja<?=$a+1?> option:selected").each(function () {
                    //var valor=$(this).val();
                    //alert(valor);
                    if ($(this).val() === "14") {
                        $("#Otro_Motivo_Baja<?=$a+1?>").prop("disabled", false);
                    } else {
                        $("#Otro_Motivo_Baja<?=$a+1?>").prop("disabled", true);
                        $("#Otro_Motivo_Baja<?=$a+1?>").val(''); 
                    }
                });
            });
        });
```

Primero escucho el select con `$("#Motivo_Baja<?=$a+1?>").on('change',function()`... al momento que se hace el cambio y se cumple la condición habilita un textarea, y si regresas el selector a su estado original, deshabilita el textarea y borra lo que hayas escrito en el.  En mi caso NO utilizo el onchange en la etiqueta del select.

El textarea por default debera estar deshabilitado para que esto funcione.

Para que me funcione la escucha del on.change  desde la base de datos traigo tres elementos, una lista de valores numericos que son el ID, una lista de claves y la lista de motivos de baja, entonces en el selector el código para tener estos valores lo imprimo así:

```
<option  id="'.$id.'" value="'.$claveMotivoBaja.'">'.$listaMotivoBaja.'</option>'
```

Con esto el select llevaría algo así en este orden ID , Clave (que no se ven), y la lista que si es visible.

- 1 clave_1 No funciona
- 2 clave_2 otra cosa
- 3 clave_3 otro cosa mas
- . .       .
- . .       .
- 14 clave_14 Otro motivo

Comment: hola ps mi select viene de un array y tiene como mil procedimientos tu codigo si llama a la funcion cada vez que cambio el select pero tengo un problema que la variable que saco del id de ese select siempre es la misma como puedo cambiar esa variable cada vez que el usuario cambie el elemento seleccionado

Comment: Checa tu select desde el explorador por que segun lo que veo solo imprimes el nombre del estudio: <option value="<?php echo $item->name; ?>"><?php echo $item->name; ?></option>

Comment: Para yo poder hacer la "comparacion" en el select le clavo el id que trae desde la tabla que es el orden en que estan guardados tanto la clave como el texto que aparece en el listado del select: echo '<option  id="'.$id.'" value="'.$claveMotivoBaja.'">'.$listaMotivoBaja.'</option>';

Comment: hola gracias solo era meter la variable dentro de la funcion y cada vez que cambia ya se actualiza su valor mil gracias llevaba todo el dia en esas

Comment: De nada espero que todo salga muy bien, buen fin!!!!.